# Is this Tense Shifting?

Tags: tenses, sequence-of-tenses

Is there tense shifting in this sentence?

***Comparing*** Q2 2016 sales volume to the same time last year, it ***was*** 2% points higher.

Or, should it be:

***Comparing*** Q2 2016 sales volume to the same time last year, it ***is*** 2% points higher.

Comment: Tense shifting usually refers to using different tenses in a piece of text. Each of your sentences has only one finite verb, so there's nothing to shift from or to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hearing this, I would at first think that the two sentences have different meanings. In the first, it ***was*** higher last year. In the second, it ***is*** higher this year.

The first statement really isn't a very good way to express this fact; because of the word order, you expect *it* to be this year's sales volume. And the 2nd quarter is presumably over (even if it just ended), so using the past tense makes some sense. But even if the 2nd quarter ended several months ago, I think the present tense is much clearer.

Tense shifting is what happens when you have reported speech in English (or have a similar situation). This isn't the case in this sentence; the reason for using the past tense would be that the 2nd quarter is past. But it's still the same year, and that's adequate justification for using the present tense, especially since the past tense leads to ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks Peter and all. What's confusing me is the word "comparing," which implies that one is looking at these sales figures -- now. And so, whichever conclusion is drawn, higher or lower, should be stated in the present, "is higher."

Comment: That reasoning doesn't work. You wouldn't say: *"Comparing Isaac Newton and Albert Einstein, Einstein is smarter."* You'd say *was* because he's no longer alive.

Comment: Going back to my original question...Q2 2016 and last year sales volumes are past. So are you saying that "was" is the better choice?